# Slow Query on salesforce_mapping_object and user table Drupal 7

Tags: mysql, drupal, web, salesforce

I have one cron written for importing items updated in Salesforce. I have one join query as below

```
SELECT a.entity_id
FROM
    salesforce_mapping_object a
  , users b
WHERE
  a.entity_id = b.uid and b.name <> '' and b.pass='' and b.status=0
limit 600
```

Both tables have around 1,30,000 + records. At peak load time, this query runs very slowly which causes my website down.

When I diagnosed this query, name<>'' condition taking too much time to scan through all records.

Can anyone give me pointers on this situation?

Comment: Ontopic: Show the table structures with `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` and query executing plan `EXPLAIN [query]` Questions about performance should atleast include these outputs.

Comment: Offtopic hint: You should not use the old comma join annymore that standard is over 25 years old..hard to read and very eazy to mis if you use a INNER JOIN or a CROSS JOIN... And using LIMIT without ORDR BY can result in different results each time you use the query. MySQL is free to return anny row matching the WHERE filter without ORDER BY.